# Is Aleinu considered a piyyut or a prayer?

Tags: song-poetry, aleinu-leshabeiach

I have always thought that Aleinu was a piyyut (liturgical poem), not a "prayer" since it does not have a bracha in it.  I was surprised to find that the Wikipedia page for [piyyut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piyyut) does not list it, and that the page for [Aleinu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleinu) calls it a prayer.  I realize that Wikipedia may not be the most authoritative source for Jewish answers, so I am asking it here.  Is Aleinu considered a piyyut or a prayer?  Either way, why?  A related (unanswered) question is: [Why are Ashre and Alenu considered communal prayers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/why-are-ashre-and-alenu-considered-communal-prayers)

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @DoubleAA  I am not entirely sure.  I had thought that tehillim, most zemirot, Aleinu, were all piyyut, but based on the answer Ypnypn submitted below, I might have my criteria wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a text can be both a prayer and a piyyut. A prayer is a type of content, whereas a piyyut is a type of style. A prayer is when one talks to God ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prayer), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prayer)); it need not contain a bracha. A piyyut is a style of a text (which may or not be a prayer) [similar to poetry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/piyyut).

Therefore, there are selections which are prayers, piyyutim, both, or none. *Mi Sheberach* is a prayer (note the absence of a bracha), but not a piyyut. *Yigdal* is a piyyut, but not a prayer. *Veye'esayu* (on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur) is a piyyut and a prayer.

Specifically, the second part of Aleinu is a prayer (since we acknowledge God as the ruler of all, and pray that He be universally recognized as such soon). It can be argued that since part of it is a prayer, the whole thing is. It is not a piyyut.