# saying aleinu with a minyon obligation

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, aleinu-leshabeiach

My Rabbi said that it is a halachah to interrupt (most places) in prayer to say aleinu together with a minyon. What is the source for this?

Comment: there is no halokho to so oleinu at all except for rosh hashono

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob And Yom Kippur in a Yovel.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22674

Answer (score 2):

I assume he means places where one is allowed to interrupt anyway (i.e., not in the middle of a *bracha*, *pesukei dzimra*, *birchat shma*, *shemoneh esrei*, etc.) in which case his source is presumably e.g. the Mishna Brurah 65:9 or Yalkut Yosef (Tefillah vol 2, p. 462) where they rule that when the congregation is saying "*Aleinu*...", one should also say it along with them (see also: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tachanun,_Ashrei,_Aleinu,_Shir_Shel_Yom ).